# Check who deleted folder from SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I recently deployed an SSIS project into the SSISDB in Integration services catalog.

```
Integration services catalog/
    SSISDB/
       project1/
       project2/
```

But recently I found that project1/ folder has been entirely deleted. How do I find out when this was deleted and which user deleted it?

Comment: Check the \bin\ and \obj\ folders in your project directory to retrieve it

Comment: @xXx The project directory itself is deleted.

Comment: Check the recycle bin on the server

Comment: @xXx - none of your suggestions are relevant to SSIS folders. These are maintained in the database not the OS

Comment: @PyMan make sure that no one changed your permissions.Packages are only visible to sysadmins and users with ssis_admin role in SSISDB Try to query the internal.

Comment: @xXx I have sysadmin access.